# How to measure accurate time offset from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2008-r2, ado, datetimeoffset

When my application starts, I'm retrieving the date/time from SQL Server using `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and comparing the difference with the local date/time - and recording this offset. Every action which records the date/time will be adjusted based on this time difference. So whenever I save any date/time, it will be that of the server - without actually querying the server numerous times each time I need it.

The problem is, let's assume this server is halfway around the world, and there's a bit of lag in the connection. I need to account for that lag too. Not the lag from request-to-response, but rather server-receives-request-to-response.

How do I measure this lag time between the moment that the SQL Server obtains its current date/time to the moment when my application receives it?

Considering SQL Server is such a powerful database engine, I would assume there's some built-in trick to accommodate for this.

Comment: I'm curious what the application is that requires this precision.  If you need to know the precise time at the server site, the question of network lag might be the least of your problems.

Comment: Would it not be better to sync all your servers to a common time source, and store all dates via `GETUTCDATE()`

Comment: It's an already well developed legacy application with a transactional structure, which currently has a very poor method of keeping track of time. Everything is recorded as the server's date/time, but it queries the server every single time it needs it. I'm tweaking it in an attempt to make it more accurate and better performing, while keeping our database structure in-tact (no major changes). If it were in early development, I would be using UTC.

Comment: I ask about the application so that we can guage how precise your answer needs to be, and what would a reasonable effort to expend to get a precise answer.   Would it be worth it to set up a GPS at each site.  Query the GPS on the server site as the signal leaves, and query the GPS on the receiving site as it arrives.   This is just a thought off the top of my head -- I should admit that I know nothing about "data communication theory" beyond knowing that this is not a trivial problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more generic problem actually in data communication theory, not just a SQL Server thing. One way to tackle it would be to do a 3 or 5 way handshake in the start and find the median time of one ACK. Then use that as Delta for all future communications.

In SQL Server case, you could run a very simple query like `SELECT 1` and check how much time it takes to get back results. One pitfall here is to avoid using any low-level mechanism like TCP (in case u have control of the server side too) because executing a query will make sure the total delta you compute includes the time for SQL Server to receive the query and parse it etc. as well.

Comment: So you mean do that 3 or so times and measure the average half-way time?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means precisely.

Comment: This would work, but I would consider it a dirty solution. +1 but I'll wait if someone has a more precise solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to be sure.  Consider that request-to-receipt takes 3 seconds.  It's possible that it took 2 seconds for request to get to the server, and 1 second for the answer to get back to you.  Or perhaps it took 1 second for request-to-server and 2 seconds for server-to-receipt.

You could assume that the two are about equal and just divide the total delay by two. You might want to make several samples and average them.

Consider also that the delay will vary over time. A request you send now might have a delay of 1 second, but a request sent an hour from now might take half that time or double that time, depending on the load on the network.

Comment: Great information to consider, yet not necessarily solving the question.

Comment: There likely won't be a solution